# Add a list element after another list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have some inputs for my users, and I want them to be able to hit a button to add another row of inputs. I am trying to use jQuery to add a list of inputs after the first.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
$("#addButton").on("click", function() {
  $("#inputs").append($("#linear"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">
  <ul class="linearFeetCalc" id="linear">
    <li><input type="number" placeholder="Quantity" id="quantity"></li>
    <li><input type="number" placeholder="Length" id="length"></li>
    <li><input type="number" placeholder="Width" id="width"></li>
    <li><input type="number" placeholder="Height" id="height"></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="stackable"> Stackable?</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="turnable"> Turnable?</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="addButton">Add Item</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very close. you just need to clone it first:

```
$("#addButton").on("click", function() {
    $("#inputs").append($("#linear").clone());
});
```

*Edit:* You should also change the ID to prevent duplicates in your DOM:

```
`...$("#linear").clone().prop('id', '#linear2')...`
```

Comment: Also the `input` elements inside the list will get duplicated with duplicate `id`s. Will that will not a problem ? @George

Comment: Oh the rabbit hole goes deeper!